# best practice for common constant variables

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a module with ~40 functions that all take `user` as a keyword argument.

`user` is not changed in any of these - it remains constant after being declared.

Is it unpythonic to declare `user` outside of the functions and not pass it in, but to reference the global variable `user`?

Comment: This kind of design is reasonable in some cases, e.g., for "config"-type variables that change how the functions in a module work, but it's generally a code smell outside of those cases. You're effectively using a module as a class instance, so why not just use a real class instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without knowing more about your use case, but this sounds like a job for a class:

```
class ComeUpWithAGoodName(object):
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
    def function1(self):
        do_stuff_with(self.user)
    # etc.
```

Comment: Maybe as a singleton/borg whatever…

Comment: @septi: I don't see any good reason to make it a singleton. Unless there's a good reason to prevent people from making multiple instances for multiple users, why try to prevent it? But of course without knowing more about the OP's design intentions, it's hard to know…

Comment: @septi For a single instance, it would not be more memory efficient, there's be exactly the same number of objects. In fact, you usually need at least one extra variable, and some extra code, to enforce a singleton/borg. For multiple objects, the assertion makes no sense as you can't have multiple objects if you enforce that there's only one. Really, there is absolutely no point.

Comment: @delnan: I wouldn't say "absolutely no point", just "usually no point". There are some rare cases where a singleton makes sense… just not nearly as many cases as people coming to Python from Java seem to think.